# Add Quotation mark to every word in string, except numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have string in this format:

```
salary,salary,200.00,10/01/2013,
```

And need to format is as following:

```
"Salary","Salary",1580.00,"2014-11-04",
```

Tried with Notepad++, but can't find out how to replace for all strings, except numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest matching and capturing what your want to avoid enclosing with double quotes (numbers) into one group, and everything else into another group. In the replacement pattern, we can specify the group that we want to enclose with double quotes using a *conditional replacement pattern*.

Use this regex:

```
(?<p1>(?:^|,)[+-]?\d+(?:[,\h]?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$))|(?<p2>[^,\r\n]+)
```

And replace with `(?{p1}$+{p1}:"$+{p2}")`

The regex contains two alternatives:

- `(?<p1>(?:^|,)[+-]?\d+(?:[,\h]?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$))` - Group `p1` matching negative and positive numbers (integer or float, with digit grouping symbols as spaces or commas and decimals as `.` - that can be adjusted further).
- `|` - or...
- `(?<p2>[^,\r\n]+)` - Group `p2` matching 1 or more symbols other than carriage return, line feed or comma.

The replacement pattern means: use Group `p1` only if it is matched (`(?{p1}$+{p1}`) or use `"` + Group `p2` + `"` if Group `p2` is matched (`:"$+{p2}")`).

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your example works much better, thanks ;) but it become problem , if I have negative digits in the string: salary,salary,-200.00,10/01/2013,  it also get quoted. Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it works best for you (a tick mark right after the down arrow on the left).

Answer (score 1):

Search this :

```
(?:^|(?<=,))([a-z]+|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})(?=,)
```

Replace with:

```
"\1"
```

**Tested on Notepad v6.6.9**